# Angular2: Can't resolve all parameters for my directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-di

I'm writing a directive which has dependencies on `TemplateRef<any>` and `ViewContainerRef`. But my directive cannot get these dependencies injected in. The following are all my code:

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloWorld } from './HelloWorld.directive';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HelloWorld],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: ` 
           Hello world!
           <template [lcngHw]="true"><div></div></template>
           `
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

HelloWorld.directive.ts

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

import { TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[lcngHw]'
})
export class HelloWorld{
    constructor(private tf: TemplateRef<any>, private vc: ViewContainerRef){

    }

    @Input()
    set lcngHw(value: boolean) {
        if (value) {
            this.vc.createEmbeddedView(this.tf);
        }
        else {
            this.vc.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my transpiled HelloWorld.directive.js:

```
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var core_1 = require('@angular/core');
var core_2 = require('@angular/core');
var HelloWorld = (function () {
    function HelloWorld(tf, vc) {
        this.tf = tf;
        this.vc = vc;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(HelloWorld.prototype, "lcngHw", {
        set: function (value) {
            if (value) {
                this.vc.createEmbeddedView(this.tf);
            }
            else {
                this.vc.clear();
            }
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    __decorate([
        core_2.Input()
    ], HelloWorld.prototype, "lcngHw", null);
    HelloWorld = __decorate([
        core_1.Directive({
            selector: '[lcngHw]'
        })
    ], HelloWorld);
    return HelloWorld;
}());
exports.HelloWorld = HelloWorld;
```

Then I run my app, and I get the following error:

**Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for HelloWorld: (?, ?).**

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HelloWorld: (?, ?).
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14268:21)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14169:28)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13944:30)
>           at eval (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14037:51)
>           at Array.forEach (native)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14031:51)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16721:49)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16659:39)
>           at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16650:23)
>           at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6707:29)
>       Evaluating http://localhost:5000/ViewContainerRefApp/main.js
>       Error loading http://localhost:5000/ViewContainerRefApp/main.js
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14268:21)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14169:28)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13944:30)
>           at eval (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14037:51)
>           at Array.forEach (native)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14031:51)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16721:49)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16659:39)
>           at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16650:23)
>           at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6707:29)
>       Evaluating http://localhost:5000/ViewContainerRefApp/main.js
>       Error loading http://localhost:5000/ViewContainerRefApp/main.js

I also copied the code from this [live sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) and I got the same error.

It seems that `TemplateRef<any>` and `ViewContainerRef`'s `metadata` are not registerd. But I cannot find out the reason. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: How do you use it? http://plnkr.co/edit/mNS3JuKcLciXcgR0WQQj?p=preview

Comment: You need to provide more code, specially your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Here you can see everything is working http://plnkr.co/edit/Indo8JByU7Cpdqb0iOO0?p=info  Also, try to put all imports from '@angular/core' in a single statement, it may be some issue with your webpack configuration if you happen to be using it.

Comment: @yurzui  Thank you for your help. Now I post all my code. Could you help me again please?

Comment: @snolflake Thank you for your help.  I have put all imports from '@angular/core' in a single statement. But I get the same error. And..I copy your code to my machine..It throws the same error.. Could you help me again please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use one of these options for structural directive:

```
<div *lcngHw="true"></div>

<template [lcngHw]="true"><div></div></template>

<div template="lcngHw true"></div>
```

This way you can inject `TemplateRef` in your component

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9HdEhJ3TVlh23RrCKoEr?p=preview)**

This also might be useful:

- [Angular2: How is ngfor expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752744/angular2-how-is-ngfor-expanded)

Comment: Have you seen my plunker example?

Comment: Could you please add your tsconfig.json?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Everything is default. There is no tsconfig.json..I will add one.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3034  http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html You need to use `--emitDecoratorMetadata` flag

Comment: Could you share your project somewhere
? I want to try it with Visual Studio 2015:)

Comment: It's solved after I add tsconfig.json with emitDecoratorMetadata set to true. Thank you veeeery much. Do you need my project after is has been solved?

Comment: Yes, i will very appreciate :)

Comment: I upload my project [here](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1hsG3fy0). It's a popular online disk in the China. Follow this link and click the '下载(8.3M)' button on the page, and then click the '立即下载' button on the modal window, then you can download it..If you cannot visit this link. I will share it on github or visual studio online tomorrow. Thank you for your help. Good night :).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a tsconfig.json, add emitDecoratorMetaData: true

If you are using Visual Studio without a tsConfig.json add the
TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata tag to your project file
Note: you will probably need more tags

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>System</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptModuleResolution>node</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
    <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
</PropertyGroup>
```