# Extra parameter always null in angular directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have the structural directive in Angular like this

```
@Directive({ selector: "[access]" })
export class AuthorizationAccessDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private eleRef: ElementRef, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    hasView: boolean = false;

    @Input("access")
    _accessInput: string[];

    @Input()
    accessFeatures: any;

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
      this.processAuthorization();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.processAuthorization();
    }
}
```

The HTML using the directive look like this

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *access="['CAD']" accessFeatures="{'Settings':31}">
...
</li>
```

I can get the `_accessInput` value, but the extra parameter `accessFeatures` is always `undefined` in both methods `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewChecked`.

I changed the value to string to simplify, but no successs as well:

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *access="['CAD']" accessFeatures="31">
```

I changed the `@Input` definition to `@Input("features")` and `@Input("accessFeatures")`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm suprised the way it works now, `*access="['CAD']"` is the wrong syntax I think, it should've been `[access]="['CAD']"`. And what is `this.processAuthorization();`?

Comment: `[access]="['CAD']" [accessFeatures]="'any'"` and `[access]="['CAD']" accessFeatures="any"` work fine for me in a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have these `inputs`

```
@Input("access")
_accessInput: string[];

@Input()
accessFeatures: any;
```

then you can use it like:

```
<li *access="['CAD']; features: {'Settings':31}">
   ...
</li>
```

(you can also omit `;` or replace with `,`)

because it will be transformed to

```
<ng-template [access]="['CAD']" [accessFeatures]="{'Settings':31}">
  <li>
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DyMykX8ZBhDOBxMqa9Le?p=preview)**

See also

- [Angular2: How is ngfor expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752744/angular2-how-is-ngfor-expanded)

P.S. If you doubt you can always check the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.0-beta.1/packages/common/src/directives/ng_component_outlet.ts#L40-L71)

Comment: I think `features` should be `accessFeatures` or you meant `@Input("features")`?

Comment: @echonax No, it should be like i wrote

Comment: Works as a charm! Thanks guys for your answer!