# Angular - How do directives "see" template & ViewContainer?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple component which injects numbers after a delay via custom directive named `*appDelay`

I already know that `*` is a hint for Angular to de-sugar the syntax into something like

```
<ng-template ...>
...actual markup
</ng-template>
```

I also know that we can Inject components/templates to the `viewContainer` via :

```
  this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView/Component(this.templateRef);
```

The directive code is :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDelay]'
})
export class DelayDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {  }
  
  @Input() set appDelay(time: number): void {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }, time);
  }
}
```

The docs states :

> To access a ViewContainerRef of an Element, you can either place a
> Directive injected with ViewContainerRef on the Element, or you obtain
> it via a ViewChild query.

**Question:**

In a *general  pseudo form* : What are the template "string values" for `templateRef` and `viewContainerRef` ?

IMHO the de-sugared template would be something like:

```
<ng-template ...>
   <card *appDelay="500 * item">
        {{item}}
   </card>
</ng-template>
```

So the `ViewContainerRef` would be a reference to `<ng-template ...>`

And the templateRef will be a reference to the `<card >...</card>`

— Is that correct ?

(Also , is it possible to `console.log()` those HTML templates and see the actual markup ?

https://plnkr.co/edit/80AGn8bR4CiyH0ceP8ws?p=preview

Comment: you might find [this article](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02) useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ViewContainerRef` just point to element that will be host for inserting views. Those views will be added as siblings to this host element.

For structural directive comment like `<!---->` will be host element.

Desugar for

```
<div *appDelay="500">
    Hooray
</div>
```

will be

```
<ng-template [appDelay]="500">
    <div>
        Hooray
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

it also can be described like so:

```
<ng-template view-container-ref></ng-template>
<!-- ViewRef -->
  <div>
    Hooray
  </div>
<!-- /ViewRef -->
```

Since `ng-template` is not stamped to the DOM it will be rendered as `<!---->`.

Angular will create `ViewContainerRef` with reference to this comment tag.

```
vcRef.element.nativeElement
```

Each ViewContainer can have only one anchor element and each anchor element can only have a single ViewContainer. ViewContainer is a container that helps you to manipulate Views(`ViewRef`, `EmbeddedViewRef`)

Also `TemplateRef` instance will be created

```
class TemplateRef_ {
  constructor(private _parentView: ViewData, private _def: NodeDef) { }

  get elementRef(): ElementRef {
    return new ElementRef(asElementData(this._parentView, this._def.index).renderElement);
  }
```

and its `elementRef`(anchor or location) will point to the same comment element.

The main feature of TemplateRef is having `template` property

```
this.templateRef._def.element.template
```

This property doesn't contains html string but describes `view`

```
this.templateRef._def.element.template.factory + ''
```

will print

```
"function View_AppComponent_1(_l) {
  return jit_viewDef1(0,[(_l()(),jit_elementDef2(0,null,null,1,'div',[],null,null,
      null,null,null)),(_l()(),jit_textDef3(null,['\n    Hooray\n']))],null,null);
}"
```

so this is our template. As you can see it describes view with `div` root element and child text node with text `\n    Hooray\n`

Angular uses such `ViewDefinitions` which are located in `ngfactories` to build the DOM tree[image]

See also

- [Angular2: How is ngfor expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752744/angular2-how-is-ngfor-expanded)
- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.0-rc.1/packages/core/src/linker/view_ref.ts#L41-L79

Don't forget to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMjTp12VbQ8

Comment: ViewContainerRef and TemplateRef are refering to the same comment tag  https://monosnap.com/file/gTzAjV2beEJm7Yp4Ujetleja7gHvpw But TemplateRef stores in its instance information about embedded template

Comment: Take a look at this example https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.0-rc.1/packages/core/src/linker/view_ref.ts#L41-L79

Comment: Hi @yurzui, what exactly is an anchor element?

Comment: @yurzui do you have an idea about that question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117068/how-can-i-change-the-viewcontainerref-of-a-ng-template

Comment: @AndreElrico I will take a look

Comment: @AndreiGătej You can think of anchor as a pointer to specific place where we can insert component or template dynamically. It's like a target element. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/475ffd67f57b0f166639728184775f2d988c8714/aio/content/guide/dynamic-component-loader.md#the-anchor-directive