# Angular's exportAs usage difference between ver 2 and 4?

Tags: angular

I have a working [**PLNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Alpv10wnZuavmVROX7Tj?p=preview) written with angular version2.
It's a simple timer where the component has a reference to the directive which contains the logic :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
    <div>
     <div class="timer" *simpleTimer="#timer=timerApi">       <-- see here
     <div class="time">{{ timer.getTime() }}</div>
      ...
    </div>
  `
```

and in the directive itself - it sets the value for `timerApi` via  :

```
  view.setLocal('timerApi', api);
```

The directive doesn't use `exportAs` :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[simpleTimer]'
})
```

I want to convert it to Angular 4. but some features doesn't work.

For example , the following code :  `*simpleTimer="#timer=timerApi"` yields  :

> Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#timer=timerApi]

Also this method `view.setLocal` doesn't exist anymore.

**Question:**

How can I reference the directive from the component ? ( so i'll have all its methods)

I've added the `exportAs` to the directive and it still doesn't work.

[**The problematic Plunker converted to ver 4.2.3**](https://plnkr.co/edit/IyiXws5oVHqFWkskmAh8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is second parameter for `vcRef.createEmbeddedView` which expects the context:

```
let api = {
  toggle: () => this.toggle(),
  reset: () => this.reset(),
  getTime: () => this.getTime()
};
let view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, { timerApi: api });
```

Usage:

```
*simpleTimer="let timer = timerApi"
```

**[Fixed Plunker v4.2.3](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q8WZNeMyU1oInY9zER5q?p=preview)**

Another option

```
let view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, { $implicit: api });
```

and template

```
*simpleTimer="let timer"
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q8d8DTrlqqSPjRKiYP7n?p=preview)**

Comment: What if simpletimer had also an @input? How woild that fit in with the assignment above?

Comment: `*simpleTimer="inputValue, yurzui: inputValue2, let timer=timerApi;"` means that your directive has `@Input` `simpleTimer` and we pass `inputValue` to it, also has `@Input simpleTimerYurzui` and we pass `inputValue2` to it

Comment: You can notice each subsequent @Input gets its name from the following pattern `simplerTimer + (Y)First character in uppercase + rest characters(urzui)`

Comment: Yuruzi I must ask you , where did you learn about the @input postfix regarding directive's base name ? I don't see it in the docs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752744/angular2-how-is-ngfor-expanded But it has changed a bit

Comment: So my answer is deep debugging

Comment: @yuruzi  -  I've just noticed : the original OP of the plunker used _structural directive_  so he can create the referenced view and add a context to it. He set the context ( which is used via `exportAs`) via `createEmbeddedView` , but  if I make it a non(!) structural directive - then I don't have this overload : `this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, { timerApi: api })`. so how can I access the object's methods inside a non-structural directive ? https://plnkr.co/edit/TVOeZYYsfG1BQ4dKi8Ug?p=preview

Comment: This  `*simpleTimer=` vs `[simpleTimer]=` vs `simpleTimer=`  is really confusing

Comment: `*simpleTimer=` is microsyntax, `[simpleTimer]` is property binding with expression, `simpleTimer="{{1+3}}"` is property binding with interpolation (@Input is always string), `simpleTimer="text"` is one-time binding

Comment: wouldn't I be able to reference `api` inside the template `<div class="time">{{ api.getTime() }}</div>` without using the context?