# How to export Structural Directive property for use in templates?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have this structural directive:

```ts
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[cycle]'
})
export class CycleDirective {
  private cycle$: any;

  constructor(
    private tRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() cycleInterval: number | Observable<any> = 1000;
  @Input() set cycle(source: Array<any[]>) {
    const interval$ = ofType(Number, this.cycleInterval) ?
      Observable.timer(0, this.cycleInterval as number) : this.cycleInterval;

    if (!hasProperty(interval$, 'subscribe')) {
      throw new Error('Input interval must be Number or Observable');
    }

    this.cycle$ = Observable.of(source)
      .combineLatest(interval$ as Observable<any>)
      .map(([items, index]) => items[cycle(index - 1, items.length)])
      .forEach(item => {
        this.vcRef.clear();
        this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tRef);
      });
  }

}
```

How do I export current item, index (or anything) to be able to use it in templates?

```
<div *cycle="['a', 'b', 'c']; interval: 2000">
  testing: <!-- current item -->
</div>
```

Ideally it should be used like `ngFor`:

```
<div *cycle="let item of ['a', 'b', 'c']; interval: 2000">{{ item }}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```typescript
this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tRef, { $implicit: item, index: index });
```

And in template:

```html
*cycle="['a', 'b', 'c']; interval: 2000; let item; let i = index"
```

For your requirement:

**directive.ts**

```typescript
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[cycle][cycleOf]'
                     ^^^^^^ but we can omit this
})
export class CycleDirective {
  private cycle$: any;

  constructor(
    private tRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() cycleInterval: number | Observable<any> = 1000;
  @Input() set cycleOf(source: Array<any[]>) {
                   ^^^ required
    ...
        this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tRef, { $implicit: item, index: index });
    ...
  }

}
```

**parent-template.html**:

```html
<div *cycle="let item of ['a', 'b', 'c']; interval: 2000; let i = index">
  {{ item }} {{ i }}
</div>
```

See also

- [Angular2: How is ngfor expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752744/angular2-how-is-ngfor-expanded)

Comment: Works perfectly (: