# Where does Angular define "as local-var" behavior for *ngIf?

Tags: angular, rxjs, open-source

I am trying to understand where is the "as local-var" optional behavior of *ngIf* defined, e.g.:
`*ngIf="user$ | async as user"`

Tried looking into obvious places in source, like
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts

But nothing in the code, only docs.

Does anyone know where in the code this magic is happening ?

Comment: Could this be inside async pipe?

Comment: Nope :) checked it aswell.

Comment: I think then it should be somewhere in the parser because we can do as on any value directive it does not really belongs to ngIf

Comment: Surely it will be somewhere in the `compiler` module?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yeah, it's magic that happens during template compilation.

The template below

```html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user"></div>
```

is just sugar for:

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="user$ | async" let-user="ngIf">
  <div></div>
</ng-template>
```

So the answer: the following string passes value to this variable:

```typescript
this._context.$implicit = this._context.ngIf = condition;
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L115

For example we can create structural directive ngVar:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngVar]',
})
export class VarDirective {
  @Input()
  set ngVar(context: any) {
    this.context.$implicit = this.context.ngVar = context;
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    this.updateView();
  }

  context: any = {};

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}

  updateView() {
    this.vcRef.clear();
    this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, this.context);
  }
}
```

and use it either like:

```html
<ng-template [ngVar]="true" let-x="ngVar"><div>{{x}}</div></ng-template>
```

or

```html
<div *ngVar="true as x">{{x}}</div>
```

---

### What's the magic?

If you want to understand where is the magic in compiler then let's take a look at an example:

```html
<div *ngVar="true as x"></div>
```

1) Angular compiler tokenizes this string like:

```html
<div *ngVar="true as x"></div>
 (1)   (2)      (3)   (4) (5)


(1) - TAG_OPEN_START
(2) - ATTR_NAME
(3) - ATTR_VALUE
(4) - TAG_OPEN_END
(5) - TAG_CLOSE
```

2) `HtmlParser` creates element's tree based on these tokens:

```html
Element div
       attrs: name:  *ngIf
              value: true as x
```

3) `TemplateParser` builds AST(abstract syntax node) tree. To do this `TemplateParser` uses special visitor called [TemplateParseVisitor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b6431c60e66d0b4cdce17dff64872ddf86e70139/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L228)

This visitor goes through all tree received in the previous step. And let's look at how it works when compiler comes to [visitElement](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b6431c60e66d0b4cdce17dff64872ddf86e70139/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L266-L425):

[image]

So as we can see any template with structural directive like:

```html
*dir="someValue as someVar"
```

represents the following:

```html
<ng-template [dir]="someValue" let-someVar="dir">
```

See also:

- https://alexzuza.github.io/enjoy-ng-parser/
- [Angular2: How is ngfor expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752744/angular2-how-is-ngfor-expanded)
- [How to declare a variable in a template in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular2/43172992#43172992)

Comment: Wow.. so its actually "let-ANYTHING" directive ? Where anything will be the name of local var ?

Comment: Looks like your post is not finished :) please continue. (I found the "as" keyword inside of the lexer, but cannot connect the dots on how "this.context.$implicit" is actually putting the variable in scope... because this IS the scope ?

Comment: There is no "let-ANYTHING" directive. Compiler just creates variable let-anything internally based on structural syntax

Comment: This way `*dir="someValue as someVar"` will be `<ng-template [dir]="someValue" let-someVar="dir">`

Comment: O, i've got it. Thanks for the thorough explanation !

Comment: This is AWESOME. BUT I just cannot understand why it is not already in the framework. And I have to believe there is a reason why it isn't there - like perhaps it wouldn't work well with change detection or some other such weirdness. Does needing such a feature mean we're doing something fundamentally wrong with out templates? Or should we all be using this?

Comment: since its implicit why can't I do this `<ng-template [ngVar]="true" let-x><div>{{x}}</div></ng-template>` notice  I had removed `let-x=ngVar`

Comment: @yurzui thanks, for quick response, So this line `this.context.ngVar = context;` is required, the way `as` syntax is de-sugared. Pretty cool.

Comment: Great explanation... but this *ngVar looks ugly. Asterisk usually means structural directive which is not in this case. Should be something out of the box in my opinion.