# Angular custom ngIf directive 'as' syntax

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I'm creating a custom *ngIf directive to replace content with a placeholder while it's loading. I have everything working as I want and modeled it after the *ngIf directive (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts) 
The only thing not working is the 'as' syntax and I don't see any references to it or where to start.

```
*myCustomDirective="loading$ | async as result"
```

The above does not work, result is undefined when the loading$ observable emits data. The placeholder is shown and replaced with the content as expected however. (Content is giving errors though because of the undefined result)

Comment: Try `"(loading$ | async) as result"`.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Updated answer**:
You can copy and paste `NgIf` directive from Angular github and the only thing you have to do is to change name of `NgIfContext#ngIf` to match your custom if directive name, for example:

```
export class NgIfContext {
  public $implicit: any = null;
  public appCustomIf: any = null;
}
```

Then change names of all `Input()` respectively to also match your directive name. With this, `as` keyword will work. See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dx4vhg) demo.

**EDIT**: As a additional reference you can follow [these commits](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15025/commits) in [#15025](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15025) pull request to see how they implemented `as` keyword in `NgIf` and `NgForOf`. In short:

1. In [a63d57f](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15025/commits/a63d57fc7914f99d066b93092b911f7b4850c7d4) they added `as` keyword to parser.
2. In [203ee65](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15025/commits/203ee653fdcb35819863a4f3270709f8da2e36cd) and [ef93998](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15025/commits/ef9399894c0f0e4f0928b014a2bcc14cf823d5ee) they converted `NgIf` and `NgForOf` respectively to use `as` syntax.
3. Finally in [71d43db](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15025/commits/71d43db702c18ad4ba8073b7df06d8666ab747bf) they exposed `NgForOfContext`,`NgIfContext` and made `NgForOf` to use `NgForOfContext`.

Also if you are curious you can see how they implemented `let` in `NgIf` by following [#13297](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13297) pull request.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616334/where-does-angular-4-define-as-local-var-behavior-for-ngif?rq=1) can help you understand what is going on underneath.

---

**Original answer:**
If you don't really care about `as` syntax and you only need working template variable this will do the job.

```
*appCustomIf="test$ | async; let result"
```

Works with copied and pasted `ngIf` from Angular github. See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dx4vhg) demo.

Comment: Can I know what I should improve because someone downvoted my answer? (meaning it's not useful)

Answer (score 4):

It's about microsyntax of Angular structural directives (https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax)

If you want you context to be exported through `as` syntax you should use **exactly the same name which your directive has** when exporting it, i.e.

```
this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, {myCustomDirective: this.context})
```

You can also use `$implicit` syntax - this will allow you to export context through `let` variable without naming it (default export).

See this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npuwxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy.directive.ts) for the details.

Comment: After some more testing it revealed that I had to make a custom NgIfContext class like the accepted answer, otherwise the component wasn't updating if subscribed to an observable.

Comment: It's strange because I've tested both variants - with async pipe and without it - you can check, I've updated my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npuwxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Could you provide me with some details what actually didn't work?

Comment: Here is a sample with *ngIf, your solution and the accepted answer solution. You can see there is some problems with your solution. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjqg1p

Comment: It's not because of `NgIfContext`. I'm just not clearing container before rerendering. See the [update example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8u64uf?file=src/app/my.directive.ts)

Comment: My mistake, yes. Looking at my change sets all I did was replace {myCustomDirective: this.context} with the NgIfContext. Previously the content wasn't getting updated when the observable emitted a new value and after the content was being updated correctly. Unfortunately I don't have time to try reproduce everything, but some edge case was causing it not to work.