# Angular ng-template use as syntax

Tags: angular

When using ngIf with the asterisk, we can do the following:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="obj | async as result">{{result}}</ng-container>
```

How can we do the same with ng-template?

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="(obs | async) as result">
    {{result}}
</ng-template>
```

The above code throws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you can also use this syntax in ng-template as follows:

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="obs | async" let-result="ngIf">
   {{result}}
</ng-template>
```

or

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="obs | async" let-result>
   {{result}}
</ng-template>
```

For more details see:

- [Where does Angular 4 define "as local-var" behavior for *ngIf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616334/where-does-angular-4-define-as-local-var-behavior-for-ngif)